# sleep function in c, unix

Tags: c, unix

What do i need to import to use the sleep function in unix? i know it's windows.h for windows, but what about unix?

Comment: In the future, you can find this sort of thing by looking at man pages. `man 3 sleep` tells you what to include for sleep. Similarly, `man 3 pow` will tell you to include `math.h` for `pow`.

Answer (score 7):

It should be in unistd.h.

Please note that this gives you only a precision of integral seconds.

The most portable way for sub-second precision should be (ab-)using select().

Comment: it depends with which *nix your using. but assuming a non-realtime linux kernel, you could use usleep for 10 millisecond accuracy.

Comment: @Yuval That's true. I just looked it up. The problem with usleep() is the varying interaction with SIGALARM - if anyone needs it ;-). BSD does implement it via nanosleep, the Single UNIX Specification mentions some problems regarding SIGALARM / alarm().

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sleep.html

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

THe man pages http://cis.kutztown.edu/~frye/cgi-bin/unixManPages.cgi?sleep+3C