# One minute while loop

Tags: c, linux, shell, unix

```
        time_t tInicio;
        time(&tInicio);
                    int TempSim=1;
        while( ( (int)difftime(time(NULL),tInicio) )<TempSim) {
            printf("TESTE");
        }
```

Im trying to make this While loop to keep going for 1 minute but its doing way less any sugestion to accomplish this ? im using unix shell

ty

Comment: From where did you get the idea that `difftime()` and `time()` measure time in minutes?

Comment: You could use the sleep function for that.

[sleep function in c, unix][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019282/sleep-function-in-c-unix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unit of time_t is seconds. Try:

```
int TempSim=60;
```

I'd advise to put some delay after the printf, or else you'll get lots and lots of output.
Perhaps: sleep(1)
Or: usleep(500 * 1000) to sleep 500ms.